# Issues with Web Scraping in Python, putting desired tags into list results in some empty and some not empty contents of the list

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping and I am using BeautifulSoup to do that

My problem is that when I put the desired contents into the list from another list which includes some tags, the second list has some missing values.

[Here is my list from which I am getting values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhhNX.png)

From this list I want to create a one which consists of the review so I use

```
names = []
for item in basic_info:
  for i in item:
    names.append(i.find_all("p", attrs = {"class" : "review-body"}))
```

The problem is that output looks like this

[The output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXwKW.png)

So basically instead of having values one by one I am getting them every other place in the list so first is empty, second has data, third is empty and then fourth has data and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** *Providing all relevant information as text instead of image would be great.*

Assuming you like to extract the several review informations, you should select all the containers and iterate over to scrape and store structured data:

```
data = []

for e in soup.select('div.consumer-review-container'):
    data.append({
        'review-title':e.h3.text,
        'review-type':e.select_one('div.review-type').text,
        'review-section':e.select_one('p.review-body').text
    })
```

##### Example

```
sample = '''
<div class="sds-container consumer-review-container">
    <h3 class="sds-heading--7 title">Excellent Car</h3>
    <div class="review-byline review-section">
      <div>June  8, 2021</div>
      <div>By ValC from Fairfield, CT</div>
        <div class="review-type"><strong>Owns this car</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-section">
      <p class="review-body">I love that BMW makes a mid size suv that is part electric now. We purchased the x3 edrive. I do mostly local driving during the week so only need to fill up with gas once a month to every six weeks. Excellent car!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sds-container consumer-review-container">
    <h3 class="sds-heading--7 title">Best Purchase for the Value and Cost</h3>
    <div class="review-byline review-section">
      <div>June  7, 2021</div>
      <div>By Brandon from Peachtree City from Peachtree City, GA</div>
        <div class="review-type"><strong>Owns this car</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-section">
      <p class="review-body">The BMW X3 is not a crossover that should be ignored. It is more than I expected coming from someone who has owned a 3 Series BMW for the last 6 years. Now I ask myself, why didn't I opt for the X3 much sooner, especially since it is more spacious with better features than my 3 series. Plus the price was only about $3,000 more for plenty more space and amenities. You owe it to yourself to test drive one soon!</p>
    </div>
</div>

'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)

data = []

for e in soup.select('div.consumer-review-container'):
    data.append({
        'review-title':e.h3.text,
        'review-type':e.select_one('div.review-type').text,
        'review-section':e.select_one('p.review-body').text
    })
    
print(data)
```

###### Output

```
[{'review-title': 'Excellent Car',
  'review-type': 'Owns this car',
  'review-section': 'I love that BMW makes a mid size suv that is part electric now. We purchased the x3 edrive. I do mostly local driving during the week so only need to fill up with gas once a month to every six weeks. Excellent car!'},
 {'review-title': 'Best Purchase for the Value and Cost',
  'review-type': 'Owns this car',
  'review-section': "The BMW X3 is not a crossover that should be ignored. It is more than I expected coming from someone who has owned a 3 Series BMW for the last 6 years. Now I ask myself, why didn't I opt for the X3 much sooner, especially since it is more spacious with better features than my 3 series. Plus the price was only about $3,000 more for plenty more space and amenities. You owe it to yourself to test drive one soon!"}]
```

Comment: Sorry for providing the necessary information as image instead of text, it is my first stackoverflow post. Besides thank you very much for your help now it works fine.